# Where is the Padding property for ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

Label and CheckBox have a "Padding" property.
This is very convenient if I want to set their position in a TableLayoutPanel.
Now I wanted to do the same with a ComboBox but to my surprise I didn't find a Padding property in the ComboBox.

Is it really not there?
If not, is there a workaround to set the indentation of a combobox indentation in a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: It is there, because a ComboBox is a Control. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx. Further, it's probably hidden with something like `[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`. But you should be able to set it from code, even if you don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ComboBox derives from Control, it does exist. It has the property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx

But the devs intentionally hid it for ComboBoxes. Here is the signature of ComboBox.Padding

**ComboBox [from metadata]**

```
//
// Summary:
//     This property is not relevant for this class.
//
// Returns:
//     A System.Windows.Forms.Padding value.
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Padding Padding { get; set; }
```

Apparently, `This property is not relevant for this class.`

Not to say you can't *try* to modify it from code at runtime...

```
this.comboBox1.Padding = new Padding(10); // this compiles!
```

...but this doesn't seem to do anything.

A TableLayoutPanel has padding itself. Maybe this would work for you

Comment: This is the kind of comment that I would hate myself for after 2 years... :-) No explanation why it's not relevant.

Comment: But TableLayoutPanel doesn't have Padding for each row / col, only for itself, right?

Comment: It has Padding and Margin. Padding should handle what you were doing with the other controls, but will apply to all of them. You may want to first set the tlp Padding according to the ComboBox, then adjust the others individually.

Comment: Place your combobox inside a panel, use the panel's padding and add the panel to your tablelayoutpanel.